# After upgrade from Centos 8 to Oracle Linux 8 the VM does not boot

Tags: centos, hyper-v

After upgrade from Centos 8 to Oracle Linux 8 the VM does not boot and Grub Rescue is shown.
I've checked the Hyper-V settings and I saw that I have two efi firmwares. [image]

Whichever I choose, the Grub Rescue menu is shown.
Right before restart, I've checked the paths and the centos path does not contain the shimx64.efi file, and redhat does. Before update, the shimx64.efi was in /boot/efi/EFI/centos/ directory and after the update and reboot in /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/ directory.

I did the full OS update to OL8 by disabling the following packages in yum.conf

```
exclude=grub2* shim-x64* kernel*
```

But that is suboptimal solution.

How can I boot the system after updating exluded packages?

Comment: Remove `quiet rhgb` from kernel options, boot, make a screenshot, edit your post and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the content of both
`/boot/efi/EFI/centos` and `/boot/efi/EFI/redhat`, I've noticed that `grub.cfg` is missing from the redhat directory.

After copying it from the centos directory and running `grub2-mkconfig` the VM was successfully booted.

`/boot/efi/EFI/centos` directory was deleted and the system boot was not affected although in hypervisor I can still see both shimx64.efi files.